# Resolving conflicts in Cocoapods submodule

Tags: ios, xcode, afnetworking, cocoapods

I am using a library in Github that happens to have AFNetworking 2.4.1 as it's submodule. However, there is another class in my project that uses AFNetworking whose version is I have no idea of seems to be conflicting with each other. Is there anyway that I can make use of AFNetworking 2.4.1 as a submodule, and use another version of AFNetworking on another class?

Comment: I believe, you can remove prior `AFNetworking `, just bluntly delete it. And new one will take over.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use same version `AFNetworking 2.4.1` for both of your modules?
You can do it by specifying in `Pod file` to download specific version for you. For example:

```
pod 'AFNetworking', '2.4.1'
```

Comment: Because these 2 modules weren't written by me. The first one was there added manually in the project and came along with AFNetworking classes. The other one I added using cocoapods and it uses AFNetworking as a submodule.